# Can't find an html label when loading html

Tags: javascript, html, load

I am able to load a simple html file but when I try to find an element within the loaded html, javascript cannot find the element.  In IE10 the loaded html is shown but the label does not change.  In Chrome, the loading does not work.  Am I loading incorrectly and is there a way to get a reference to the element?

The progress.html simply has one line in it a label with an id of `"progressLabel"` and innerText of "`Loading...`", that's it.

I am creating a modal dialog then loading and then trying to get the progresslabel:

```
$("#progressbarDiv").dialog({
    resizable: false,
    height: 240,
    width: 500,
    modal: true,
    closeOnEscape: false,
    //disabled: true,
    open: function (event, ui) {
        // Hide close button 
        $(this).parent().children().children(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
    },
    buttons: {
        "Ok": {
            text: "OK",
            id: "myOKButton",
            click: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        } 
    }
});
$('#progressbarDiv').load('progress.html');
var testThis = $('#progressLabel');
testThis.text = "...Synchronizing data, please wait...";
```

Comment: you have not mentioned if y ou are using jQuery or some library. Perhaps that library is not loaded?

Comment: Should we assume this is wrapped in a `.ready()` container? Also, can you post some HTML?

Comment: `$(this).parent().children().children(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close")` could be cleaner by writing `$(this).parent().find(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close")` unless you have more than one dialog titlebar-close in the children...

Comment: `load()` is going to by asynchronous so  if it is inside of `progressbarDiv` it probably isn't present immediately after the load. Also you need to target the content container part of the dialog or you are just wiping out the dialog contents of `progressbarDiv`.

Comment: `testThis.text = "...Synchronizing data, please wait...";` doesn't really do anything, does it? Wait, it does, it overrides [jQuery.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) Use `testThis.text("...Synchronizing data, please wait...")` ?

Comment: @scrappedcola thank you for the heads up on the content container.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access the HTML in an AJAX-loaded element, you need to perform the Javascript in a callback function.

```
$('#progressbarDiv').load('progress.html',function(){
    // Your script was setting $.text = , but it's a function.
    $('#progressLabel').text("...Synchronizing data, please wait...");
});
```

`$.load(url, callback)` is asynchronous, therefore the content is not loaded when `$.load` returns. The `callback` is how you know `$.load` has finished its processing

You can use `$('#progressLabel').text("...Synchronizing data, please wait...");` anywhere in your script. If it's a small enough project, it's OK. If you care about maintenance, you should architecture your code so it doesn't require global access to that div from everywhere. At the very least create a function that can be called to do it, maybe it could load it on demand?

```
/**
 * A simple but slightly better way to set the text from anywhere. 
 * Lazily fetches the progress HTML.
 */
function setProgressString(str) {
    function setText() {
        $('#progressLabel').text(str);
    }

    if ($('#progressLabel').length === 0) {
        $('#progressbarDiv').load('progress.html', setText);
    } else {
        setText();
    }    
}

// Use anytime
setProgressString('...Synchronizing data, please wait...')';
```

Comment: I don't think `#progressLabel` is in the loaded data

Comment: @Ian "... when I try to find an element within the loaded html,"

Comment: @JuanMendes You are quite right, I'm not sure how I missed that. Haha sorry

Comment: "If it is outside of a callback function, the original run of the jQuery/Javascript will not see it" doesn't really explain the problem, or could be clearer. It's the fact that `$.load` is _asynchronous_, therefore the content is not loaded when `$.load` finishes, the callback is how you know `$.load` has finished its processing

Comment: @Vangel Your recent questions were not as common as someone not understanding the asynchronous nature of `$.load` Please don't add random comments to answers

Comment: This fixes the initial call but how do I then set the label in other places in code?  Sorry I am new to javascript.

Comment: @Juan. chill dude. It was light humor.

Comment: @indianapolymath In code outside of this script, you'll have to check that it's been loaded in some way (running the same query again and checking for results?), it's outside of the scope of the question to suggest some architecture of how to tell that

Comment: wow, i missed a lot. thanks for the more detailed explanation @JuanMendes, i just wanted to get something quick and dirty out there but that is a much better explanation.

Comment: @indianapolymath Doing `$('#progressLabel').text("...Synchronizing data, please wait...")` from anywhere will do the only thing that can be done... Write it if it's there, ignore it if it's not.

Answer (score 0):

Wait until the entire page has loaded before you try accessing the element.

Comment: Do you mean use `$.ready()` or the `$.ajax` callback? Showing code would improve the answer

Comment: I click a button after the initial page is loaded to execute the above dialog.  I am assuming that the html is added to the DOM during the load but let me check.